# What's wrong with this gzip format?

Tags: python, http, gzip

I use the following python code to download web pages from servers with gzip compression:

```
url = "http://www.v-gn.de/wbb/"
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
content = response.read()
response.close()

import gzip
from StringIO import StringIO
html = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(content)).read()
```

This works generally, but for the specified URL fails with a `struct.error` exception.
I get a similar result if I use wget with an "Accept-encoding" header. However, browsers seem to be able to decompress the response.

So my question is: is there a way I can get my python code to decompress the HTTP response without resorting to disabling compression by removing the "Accept-encoding" header?

For completeness, here's the line I use for wget:

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla" --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" http://www.v-gn.de/wbb/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you can call `readline()` on the `gzip.GzipFile` object, but
`read()` raises a `struct.error` because the file ends abruptly.

Since `readline` works (except at the very end), you could do something like this:

```
import urllib2
import StringIO
import gzip
import struct

url = "http://www.v-gn.de/wbb/"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
content = response.read()
response.close()
fh=StringIO.StringIO(content)
html = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO.StringIO(content))
try:
    for line in html:
        line=line.rstrip()
        print(line)
except struct.error:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran the command you specified. It downloaded a gzip-ed data into `index.html`. I renamed `index.html` into `index.html.gz`. I tried `gzip -d inedx.html.gz` which lead to an error: `gzip: index.html.gz: unexpected end of file`.

Second try was `zcat index.html.gz` which **worked** fine except that after the `</html>` tag it printed the same error as above.

```
$ zcat index.html.gz
...
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
gzip: index.html.gz: unexpected end of file
```

The server is faulty.

Answer (score 3):

Create your handler by deriving from urllib2.HTTPHandler and overriding http_open().

```
import gzip
from StringIO import StringIO
import httplib, urllib, urllib2
class GzipHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
    def http_open(self, req):
        req.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
        r = self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
        if (
            'Content-Encoding'in r.headers and
            r.headers['Content-Encoding'] == 'gzip'
        ):
            fp = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(r.read()))
        else:
            fp = r
        response = urllib.addinfourl(fp, r.headers, r.url, r.code)
        response.msg = r.msg
        return respsone
```

then build your opener.

```
def retrieve(url):
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(GzipHandler)
    return opener.open(request)
```

the differences are this method checks that the server returns a gzip response and its done during the request not after.

For more information see:

- http://diveintopython3.ep.io/http-web-services.html
- https://derrickpetzold.com/index.php/python-gzip-http/

Comment: This doesn't really address the original question, but is indeed the proper way to do this. I still have concerns about faulty servers that return a "Content-encoding: gzip" header but actually send the data raw.

Comment: Did you try it? It worked for me. I got back a 151860 length response that uncompressed. The other implementations posted here were buggy and I didn't go through them. Perhaps a at later time.

Comment: Yeah, the website in the original question seems to have fixed their problem, so I don't have a good way to test. In either case the problem would be addressed by using `readline()` instead of `read()`, which is done outside of `retrieve()` anyway.